# Newton Raphson Method Iteration Scheme

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

[image]

---

My question here is for the 2nd part. The 1st part is straightforward, taking $x^2 - N = 0$ as $f(x)$. How does one go about the second part? What exactly do they mean by applying the scheme two times?

Edit: By second part, I mean how does one derive that formula "easily"!

Comment: if $N=2$ and $A=1$ then $B=2$, so estimate the value of $\sqrt{N}$ using the formula you derived

Comment: From the second part, the 3rd part is also easy. My question is about the 2nd part ~ that is, how the formula was derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A_k=x_k$ and $B_k=N/x_k$, then
$$
x_2=\frac{A_1+B_1}2=\frac{x_1}2+\frac{N}{2x_1}=\frac{A_0+B_0}4+\frac{N}{A_0+B_0}
$$
And as $x_2$ is indeed a better approximation for $\sqrt N$, one can write $\sqrt{N}\approx x_2=...$